# Where should the pure virtual destructor be declared?

Tags: c++, memory-leaks, linker-errors, virtual-destructor

EDIT: Apparently the question is not clearly formulated enough. The issue I am having is that when the destructor is defined in the header it gets added into multiple .obj files and the linker complains. The actual question is:

When I add the destructor to a CPP file in a DLL project and use the dll with dynamic loading and the interface header file, does the base destructor still get called to prevent leaking memory?

I am using MSVC 10.0 and have a DLL project that implements an interface. The interface is an abstract (pure virtual) base class. The idea is that the header is used with dynamic loading of the library. Therefore, I have used a pure virtual destructor to make sure the destructor in the base class gets called. Here is sample code to explain this:

```
//ISplitter.h
#pragma once

struct param {
    int something;
}

class ISplitter {
public:
    virtual ~ISplitter() = 0;
    virtual void useful() = 0;
}

ISplitter::~ISplitter() {
    /* Make sure base class destructor gets called */
}
```

And the main implementation header

```
//CSplitter.h
#pragma once
#include "CHelper.h"
#include "ISplitter.h"


class CSplitter : public ISplitter {
private:
    CHelper hlp;
public:
    ~CSplitter();
    void useful();
}
```

Some helper class

```
//CHelper.h
#pragma once
#include "ISplitter.h" // I need the struct

// Class definition should go here but is irrelevant
```

Now the problem is that the linker generates an error that tells me the destructor: ISplitter::~ISplitter(void) has been multiply declared and the system will not build.
Error:

```
CHelper.obj : error LNK2005: "public: virtual __cdecl ISplitter::~ISplitter(void)" (??1ISplitter@@UEAA@XZ) already defined in CSplitter.obj
```

What is the correct way to fix this? I have placed the destructor in ISplitter.cpp, but I am worried this may not work if I dynamically load the library and upcast the base class to ISplitter.

Comment: Please post real code. And the answer is to move the destructor definition to a.cpp file.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Pure virtual destructor in C++](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/630950/pure-virtual-destructor-in-c)

Comment: @Neil: Or to make the destructor not pure virtual in the first place. Why not just an empty virtual destructor?

Comment: @Wouter We don't need to see the original code, but we do need to see real C++ code that illustrates the problem. For example, here `ISplitter::ISplitter()` I assume there is a missing `~`?

Comment: @Neil: I apologize, it is missing that and that is a critical error. Apologies and fixed.

Comment: If you define a function, destructor or not, in a header you must make it `inline`. That solves the multiple definition problem.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem is that the base class destructor *always* gets called- but in this case, you've made it pure virtual, so it doesn't exist. The only reason to make a destructor pure virtual to is to enforce a class to be abstract when you have no other members. The destructor of a class needs to be defined in all cases.

Edit: I mis-read your code. Just define the destructor virtually inline.

`virtual ~ISplitter() {}`

There's no need for any pure virtual here, since you already have other pure virtual members.

Comment: It does exist, hence the multiple-definition errors, though this is not obvious from his "pseudocode".

Comment: I believe that is what I prefer, much cleaner and I am sure that it will always be there. So I am accepting this answer.

Comment: +1 for "Just define the destructor inline", except I can't vote yet. He could also make the definition inline by qualifying the out-of-line definition of the destructor with inline.

Comment: I think the inline keyword is handled differently based on optimization settings

Comment: @WouterSimons the `inline` keyword mostly means "silently discard if this is defined in more than one compilation unit" (with some extra stuff about address-of), and member functions in `class` or `struct` bodies are implicitly `inline`.  Under the C++ standard, it doesn't have much to do with inlining methods.

Answer (score 4):

Sharptooth's answers is correct in that you HAVE to provide a definition to the pure virtual destructor ([see this GotW](http://www.gotw.ca/gotw/031.htm)). But it is wrong in that you cannot write

```
virtual ~A() = 0 {};
```

according to this clause in the standard (although many compilers support this extension)

***Clause 10.4 paragraph 2*** of C++03 tells us what an abstract class is and, as a side note, the following:

*[Note: a function declaration cannot provide both a pure-specifier and a definition
—end note] [Example:*

```
struct C {
virtual void f() = 0 { }; // ill-formed
};
```

*—end example]*

See [this question of mine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4174694/pure-virtual-functions-may-not-have-an-inline-definition-why) for more details