# = operator in function prototype

Tags: c++, function-prototypes

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Pure virtual functions may not have an inline definition. Why?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4174694/pure-virtual-functions-may-not-have-an-inline-definition-why)

I've come accross a function prototype that looks like this:

```
    virtual void functionName(const int x) = 0;
```

what does that =0 exactly mean?

Comment: @Alf P. Steinbach: The two questions are similar but not the same, IMHO.

Comment: @DarkDust: Still it's worth to look at that question. It explains why it's incorrect to state that the class does not provide implementation for the pure virtual method.

Comment: @DarkDust: I agree they're not identical, but AFAICS there's no option to say "this question is part of and is answered by that other question"

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This denotes purely virtual (abstract) function. Class containing such function is automatically abstract and any class deriving from it you want to instantiate must implement this function.

Answer (score 0):

It means that this function is pure virtual and won't be implemented in this class.
Also this means that the class is an abstract one because it contains a pure virtual function.
So you can not make instances of classes that contain pure virtual functions.

Comment: -1 "and won't be implemented in this class" this is incorrect.

Comment: Learning everyday. Thx to point that out for me. But it leaves me with the question: How often are those pure functions implemented in the class that declared them pure?

Comment: I guess I am programming the wrong things :) I never had an abstract class that needed an destructor, because all my abstracts were mere interfaces.

Comment: @Nobody: even if the destructor doesn't do anything, it's still nominally there. Destructors are special, marking them virtual doesn't really mean that the derived class destructor is called "instead of" the base class destructor, since base class destructors are nominally called *as well as* the derived class destructor, even if one or both of the destructors doesn't actually do anything.

Answer (score 0):

It means that function is abstract, with out any implementation, and you have to implement this function in derived class.

Comment: -1 "with out any implementation" this is incorrect: there can be an implementation (in the same class that declares it pure virtual).

Answer (score -1):

This means that `functionName` is a *pure virtual* method. That is, the class does not provide an implementation for the method, subclasses need to implement it.

This is often used for base classes that want to define a method that every subclass needs to implement and for which no meaningful default can be provided.

Comment: Subclasses (only those that you want to instantiate) must indeed override this method but the abstract class might still provide its implementation.

Comment: -1 "the class does not provide an implementation for the method" this is incorrect, as noted by @Rafal.